# How to count records per ranged partition within a single select in oracle 12c?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

The solution I'm looking for (if it exists) is to directly partition by the actual partition and ***not*** by a calculated value.

**Table Pseudo-Code:**

```
create table table_1 as (part_col DATE, val_col VARCHAR2(1))
partition by range part_col (
   PARTITION t_20160515 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2016-05-15','YYYY-MM-DD'))
   PARTITION t_20160516 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2016-05-16','YYYY-MM-DD'))
   ...
);
```

**Select Pseudo-Code:**

```
select partition as P, count(*) as C from table_1
group by partition;
```

**Desired Result**

```
  P        |  C
-----------|-----
2016-05-15 | 8
2016-05-16 | 99
```

**Works but not what I'm looking for:**

```
select trunc(part_col) P, count(*) C from table_1;
```

Comment: Consider using a system table? `Select partition_name, num_rows from all_tab_partitions ` or `dba_tab_partitions`  Though table stats not being run will make the rowcount not match.... so probably not what you're after

Comment: You could run this take the results remove the last union all and then run the select... `Select table_name, partition_name, num_rows from all_tab_partitions where table_name = 'AUD_HIST3'
partition_name, table_name 
SELECT 'SELECT ' || chr(39) || partition_Name || chr(39) || ', count(*) FROM ' ||table_name ||' partition (' || partition_name || ') UNION ALL '  as test
from all_tab_partitions where table_Name = 'Table_1'`

Comment: yeah, the counts are null. on the dba table and i have no control over that.

Comment: I'll see how that performs. I'm a little worried about using unions over 90 partitions.

Comment: @ScrappyDev If the counts are null that implies that statistics have not been gathered.  That should only happen for a new table or if someone intentionally disabled the default statistics job.  A simple call like `begin dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TABLE_1'); end; /` would make the `num_rows` column 100% accurate.

Comment: What would using the partition name accomplish that doing a `trunc(part_col)` would not?  In both cases, if you want an accurate count, you're going to have to at least full-scan an index on every partition (assuming there is a locally partitioned index on a non-nullable column).  The `select` you have but don't want should do that about as efficiently as it can be done while giving Oracle as much freedom for parallelism as possible.  Dynamically building a query that hits each partition explicitly and does a `UNION ALL` of the result won't be more efficient and will be a lot uglier...

Comment: @JustinCave I agree, but since the question involved not using it...

Comment: if you can group by partition, there are performance tweaks you can make.

Comment: Also, note that there are ~500,000 records in each of the partitions and I care about 90 of the 774 partitions..

Comment: @Jon Heller - I don't have DBA access to the table and can't kick off the stats.

Comment: If you care about 90 partitions, just add a `WHERE` clause that limits yourself to the 90 partitions that you care about.  Partition pruning is likely to be much more efficient than what you are going to be able to build.

Comment: @ScrappyDev You don't need DBA permissions to gather statistics.  The owner of an object can gather stats on it.  If there is a process that's significantly changing the data then that process should also be gathering stats.

Comment: My login is not the owner of the object.

Comment: And when i refered to "DBA" I meant my role, not "AS SYSDBA".

Answer (score 5):

Run this to generate a set of selects for each partition

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' || chr(39) || partition_Name || chr(39) || ', count(*) 
        FROM ' ||table_name ||' partition (' || partition_name || 
        ') UNION ALL ' as test 
FROM all_tab_partitions 
WHERE table_Name = 'Table_1'
```

Results in something like:

```
SELECT 'P1', count(*) FROM Table_1 partition (P1) UNION ALL 
SELECT 'P2', count(*) FROM Table_1 partition (P2) UNION ALL 
SELECT 'P3', count(*) FROM Table_1 partition (P3) UNION ALL 
SELECT 'P4', count(*) FROM Table_1 partition (P4) UNION ALL 
SELECT 'P5', count(*) FROM Table_1 partition (P5) UNION ALL
```

Copy and paste results removing last union all and then run.  Not so sure about performance...  I hit a table with 5 partitions and it completed in about 2 sec total rows only around 5 mil.

Comment: That works well and performs better than a select w/ trunc(date) over 90 partitions. Each partition has around 500,000 rows in it. If no better solutions are found, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: gotta admit i'm a bit shocked that it performed better.... Are you sure that it didn't leverage what was already cached or the execution plan for both shows this really being more optimal?  though a trunc on 500,000*90 might be a bit much...

Comment: I was surprised, too. and I compared both first runs and both second runs. I did not try over the whole table though. (and don't intend to).
I also checked the explain plans and saw the same result: Union ALL was better.

Comment: The only problem w/ this approach is that you have to re-generate the query every day.

Comment: Not necessarily, you could write it up as a procedure and use `exec` for the  dynamic SQL string that truncates the last union all; or write those results to a temp table and select from it.  lots of options.

Comment: That's true, but since this is in production, creating a procedure or function is not an option. It's got to be a read-only solution.

Comment: Yep, that about ruins all the ideas I would have.

Answer (score 1):

The query can count the rows in each partition for a given partitioned table as below.

```
select table_name ,Partition_name,high_value ,
 to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select /*+ parallel(a,8) */
count(*) c from '||table_name||' partition ('||partition_name||') a ')),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as count 
from user_tab_partitions where table_name='LINEORDER';

LINEORDER   P1  TO_DATE(' 1900-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') 0
LINEORDER   SYS_P4365   TO_DATE(' 1996-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') 108
LINEORDER   SYS_P4366   TO_DATE(' 1994-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') 142
LINEORDER   SYS_P4367   TO_DATE(' 1995-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') 186
LINEORDER   SYS_P4368   TO_DATE(' 1997-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') 175
LINEORDER   SYS_P4369   TO_DATE(' 1998-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') 213
LINEORDER   SYS_P4370   TO_DATE(' 1993-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') 128
LINEORDER   SYS_P4371   TO_DATE(' 1999-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') 47
```

Comment: nice solution but I would suggest putting an anonymous block as wrapper. Pass the table name to a procedure that does the PARTITION name lookup and the count. This way you will have a generic procedure and people can modify the wrapper if needed